# Factor out random variable from expected value

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

Consider three  random variables $Z_k, Z_l, X$ with $k <l $
I want to calculate: $$E(Z_k Z_l | X \geq l)$$

Why is it possible to factor $Z_k$ out.

Maybe I know the values for $Z_k$  because $l<k$
?

Comment: what do you mean by "to factor $Z_k$ out" ?

Comment: I mean $Z_k E( Z_l | X \geq l)$

Comment: I don't see any reason.

Comment: ok then it is not possible

Comment: You have to provide more information to get an accurate answer. If $Z_k$ is conditionally independent of $Z_l$ given $X \geq l$, then indeed $E[Z_k Z_l | X \geq l] = Z_k E[Z_l | X \geq l]$. Perhaps $Z_k$ is completely determined given $X \geq l$ and $l > k$, in which case $E[Z_k Y | X \geq l] = Z_k E[Y | X \geq l]$ for any random variable $Y$. Maybe $Z_i$ are i.i.d. $\{0,1\}$-valued random variables and $X$ is the "first time" $Z_i = 1$? In which case $X \geq l > k$ implies $Z_k = 0$.

Comment: Yes it is completely determined given $X  \geq l$ Sorry for the lack of information. So you can say, that $Z_k$ is measurable?